# Animating the visibility of a usercontrol

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls, visibility

I've got a usercontrol that defines storyboards for visibility hide & show (Root is the top-level grid control in the usercontrol):

```
<Storyboard x:Key="VisibleStoryboard">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" KeyTime="0" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" From="0" To="1" Duration="{StaticResource Duration}" />

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="{StaticResource Duration}"/>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="CollapsedStoryboard">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" KeyTime="{StaticResource DurationKeyTime}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" From="1" To="0" Duration="{StaticResource Duration}" />

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="{StaticResource Duration}"/>
</Storyboard>
```

I'm applying these storyboards when the visibility of the control changes:

```
static MyControl()
{
    VisibilityProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Warning), new PropertyMetadata(VisibilityChanged));
}

private static void VisibilityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)d;

    switch ((Visibility)e.NewValue)
    {
        case Visibility.Visible:
            ((Storyboard)element.FindResource("VisibleStoryboard")).Begin(element);
            break;
        case Visibility.Collapsed:
            ((Storyboard)element.FindResource("CollapsedStoryboard")).Begin(element);
            break;
    }
}
```

The visible storyboard works fine. However, the collapsed storyboard isn't working, as the user control visibility is immediately being set to Collapsed, making it disappear before the storyboard can run.

How can I delay or override actually settings the user control visibility until after the storyboard has taken effect?